# Undefined full name in Ajax response

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a User.php model.

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    if($this->first_name && $this->last_name) {
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    } else {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

In the blade file, if we want to get it, I write it like this.

```
{{ $user->full_name }}
```

But I don't know how to do it in Ajax. I wrote the following code, and it displayed `undefined`.

```
<strong class="f20 mb-1">`+user.full_name+`</strong>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX response, you need to make sure that the `full_name` attribute is appended to the user model. Laravel does not automatically append accessor attributes when converting a model to an array or JSON. You can do this by adding an `$appends` property to your `User` model:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $appends = ['full_name'];

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        if($this->first_name && $this->last_name) {
            return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
        } else {
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, `$appends = ['full_name'];` tells Laravel to include the `full_name` attribute when converting the user model to an array or JSON. Now, `full_name` should be available in your AJAX response.